# Powershell GUI - Classic Theme instead of Windows Aero

Tags: user-interface, powershell, aero

When creating a GUI-Programm in **Powershell ISE**, it's **Windows Aero** themed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiZlE.png

Running the same programm from **Desktop**, it's Theme is **Windows Classic**.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKp5S.png

I want to be able to use the aero theme when running the program from a .bat. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to include the code for your GUI so we can help.

Comment: Found it:

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

[From Here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/07/23/enabling-visual-styles.aspx)